# How can I compute minimum thickness for a rigid acrylic panel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis

If I have an acrylic (plexiglass) panel, how can I compute how thick it must be to resist bending.

So, for example, if I have a sheet that is 24" x 36" and supported by the edges only (such as in a large light fixture), how thick does the sheet have to be to be self-supporting so that it does not bend in the middle?

Comment: The answer depends how it is fixed at the edges. Also, *any* thickness of panel will "bend in the middle" - the question is how much bending is *unacceptable* for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have your acrylic material properties data sheet, such as its modulus of elasticity, E and its max stress, $\sigma s$, and poisons ratio. Usually the acceptable deflection, y ranges between $y<L/180, \ or \ y<L/360$

Then you try different thicknesses, t, till you get the smallest t with acceptable deflection.

Referring to Roark’s Formulas
for Stress and Strain, by WARREN C. YOUNG
RICHARD G. BUDYNAS seventh edition table 11.4 pp 507
For a rectangular plate simply supported at the edges uniformly loaded with q:

$$y_{max}= \frac{-\alpha qb^4}{Et^3}$$

$$ \sigma max = \sigma b = \frac{\beta qb^2}{t^2}$$

The coefficients, $\alpha \ and \ \beta $ are shown in the following table.

[image: table]

Comment: Might need to add that the plate dimensions are $a \times b$ with $a$ the long dimension